# Cannot Execute rcu.bat for installing Repository Creation Utility of Oracle BI

Tags: oracle12c, obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am installing Oracle BI on my machine after installing Oracle 12C->Fusion MiddleWare->OBI and when i try to run rcu.bat file  for installing  Repository Creation Utlity.I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0NGd.jpg)

Comment: What operating system is that?

Comment: windows 7(64-Bit)

Comment: Yasir so did you just give up? Could you comment on whether the response helped?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it. So that means no check of the documentario, none of the certification matrix and never giogled once, because.... That isn't supported and never will be :)

https://dimensionality.ch/2017/05/06/installing-oracle-bi-on-windows-7-8-10/

Answer (score 0):

- thanks for your time @chris. The issues was that i had entered
  environment  variables incorrectly.The system environment variables
  were entered in the  user variables section  and vice versa.If you
  face this  error be sure to **check your  environment variables**